# Center float left divs with twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.2. I want to display a series of divs next to each other, float: left then center that group in a full width row.  What I get are the divs lined up next to each other but the entire group floats left.

I've tried numerous suggestions from this site but have been unable to make any of them work.

I have HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="wrapBoxRow" class="row">
            <div id="boxRow" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="boxWrap">
                    <div class="smallBox"></div>
                    <div class="smallBox"></div>
                    <div class="smallBox"></div>
                    <div class="smallBox"></div>
                    <div class="smallBox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    #boxWrap, #boxRow, #wrapBoxRow
    {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .smallBox
    {
        border: 3px solid #ddd;
        float: left;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-right: 12px;
    }
```

I've tried this without bootstrap and couldn't get it to work either:

```
<div id="boxWrap">
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
    <div class="smallBox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below CSS to horizontally center your div

```
 #boxWrap, #boxRow, #wrapBoxRow
    {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

You can find working code here http://bootply.com/92723

Comment: That's really good thanks. I had got this working by giving the div I was centering a width but that wasn't ideal as the contents might vary. This approach is better.